# How to add a default namespace to an existing XSD file using C#

Tags: c#, xsd

I have an existing XSD file and I want to add a namespace.  How can I do this using C#?

Starting with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="BasicNoiseServiceRequest_201102" nillable="true" type="BasicNoiseServiceRequest_201102" />
  <xs:complexType name="BasicNoiseServiceRequest_201102">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="CrmServiceRequest">
```

I want to end up with something like this where the xmlns and targetNamespace attributes have been added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema  xmlns="MyNamespace" targetNamespace="MyNamespace" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="BasicNoiseServiceRequest_201102" nillable="true" type="BasicNoiseServiceRequest_201102" />
  <xs:complexType name="BasicNoiseServiceRequest_201102">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="CrmServiceRequest">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using XDocument for parsing and generating xml by generating a new XDocument from the loaded one.

```
// Parse a string or Load a file
var doc = XDocument.Parse(
  @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault=""qualified"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
      <xs:element name=""BasicNoiseServiceRequest_201102"" nillable=""true"" type=""BasicNoiseServiceRequest_201102"" />
      <xs:complexType name=""BasicNoiseServiceRequest_201102"">
        <xs:complexContent mixed=""false"">
          <xs:extension base=""CrmServiceRequest"">
           ...
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
  ");

// Get the root of the document
var root = doc.Root;

// Create a new XDocument and add all the required attributes
// Keep all the existing xml file (declaration, child nodes, ...)
doc = new XDocument(doc.Declaration,
  new XElement(root.Name, root.Elements(),
    root.Attributes().Concat(new[]
    {
      new XAttribute("xmlns", "MyNamespace"),
      new XAttribute("targetNamespace", "MyNamespace")
    }))
);
```